# magento 2 backend customer's order infinite loading

Tags: magento2.2.3

Here is the picture of Magento enterprise 2.2.3 in `customer->order`, anyone know what is the problem?

[image]

When ever i visit this page, there is a new line in system.log

```
[2018-06-08 04:31:53] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

-----------update-------------
I found in browser console

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Select_Exception): You cannot define a correlation name 'company_order' more than once

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Select_Exception): You cannot define a correlation name 'company_order' more than once
#0 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Select.php(297): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'main_table.enti...', Array, NULL)
#1 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php(378): Magento\Framework\DB\Select->_join('left join', Array, 'main_table.enti...', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/module-company/Plugin/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/CollectionPlugin.php(32): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'main_table.enti...', Array)
#3 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Company\Plugin\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionPlugin->beforeLoad(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor))
#4 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#5 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection/Interceptor.php(507): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)
#6 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor->load()
#7 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection/Interceptor.php(999): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#8 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid/extended.phtml(183): Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor->getIterator()
#9 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/m2vtec/pu...')
#10 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(270): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\Orders), '/home/m2vtec/pu...', Array)
#11 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/m2vtec/pu...')
#12 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(667): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#15 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('adminhtml.custo...')
#16 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.custo...')
#17 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml.custo...')
#18 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('adminhtml.custo...', true)
#19 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(585): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('adminhtml.custo...')
#20 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(536): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#21 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#22 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#23 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#24 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(954): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#25 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#26 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(182): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#27 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#28 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#29 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#30 /home/m2vtec/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#32 /home/m2vtec/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#33 {main}
```

Comment: How about opening the browser developer tools? I suspect this is JS error.

Comment: @PYYick yes, there is an error in cosole

Comment: @hkguile, You have any order attribute named `company_order` ?

Comment: @Vivek  i didn't find a attribute named company_order

Comment: I dont know what is it But its causing issue for your orders grid, Check and find what's `company_order` what's its relation with order.

Answer (score 0):

This issue are raise due to a extension `module-company`

Seems ***,Some mysql join happen happen via this extension***,

```
#2 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/module-company/Plugin/Sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/CollectionPlugin.php(32): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'main_table.enti...', Array)
#3 /home/m2vtec/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Company\Plugin\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionPlugin->beforeLoad(Object(Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection\Interceptor))
```

If you see that error then  you understand

**`Magento\Company\Plugin\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\CollectionPlugin`**
  this plugin class is responsible for this error.

**If you disabled  plugin for this class of this module then you issue will be resolved.**

Comment: I found this module is Magento_Company that is official? You mean disable this module?

Comment: It is don't thought not magento  own-mdule

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue,
This will work if you want to use company-module in Magento. 
Finally after some digging we need to add a piece of code to CollectionPlugin.php

before $subject->getSelect()

```
//bug fixes for customerinfo->ordertab
        $select = $subject->getSelect()->__toString();
        if(preg_match('/company_name/', $select)){
            return [$printQuery, $logQuery];
```